# OpenNLP and database of synonyms

Tags: opennlp

We've the database of synonyms of organization names (e.g. BT is `British Telecom`. We use OpenNLP to extract entities and keywords from text blocks. Is there a way to tell OpenNLP to use our database data (e.g. if it finds `BT` as Organization Name it should return `British Telecom`). Some kind of `hook`. Or we just have to do that manually against OpenNLP results?

Answer (score 2):

In OpenNLP 1.6 there is a new compoent called "EntityLinker"
The purpose of EntityLinker is to solve the exact problem you have... linking NER results to authoritative databases. In the opennlp addons there is an implementation of an EntityLinker that does geocoding by linking NER results to geographic placenames gazateers. OpenNLP 1.6 will be out soon but you could pull trunk.
In the meantime you could take the approach you alluded to, which is to create a class that takes in your NER results, and queries your database, and return N best matches.
Assuming your database supports "fuzzy" search, you could generate a score and return a set of  scored results

Answer (score 1):

This[1] should help. According to Apache openNLP documentation, a custom corpus can be used to train a language model.

An alternative is to use Apache Stanbol which integrates openNLP into a coherent high level platform where you can easily configure custom vocabularies for the purpose of name entity recognition [2]

[1] http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html#tools.namefind.training

[2] https://stanbol.apache.org/docs/trunk/customvocabulary.html